# Why does VISA (4111111111111111) does not return anything?

Tags: c, cs50, luhn

I am very new to programming and so, please help me with this Luhn's algorithm problem. Everything 
    works right except with a Visa 411111111111111. what actually is causing the error? I know copy 
       pasting is considered a bad code but I was trying to at least create working code. Can you help me 
       improve this code? I will be thankful for your help.

```
   ---------------------------------------------

   #include <cs50.h>
   #include <stdio.h>

    int main ()
     { // 1

       long cardnumber;
       int digits = 0;
       int even, odd;

        //  Getting credit card number
       do 
        {
        cardnumber = get_long("Enter your card number:\n"); 
        }
        while (cardnumber < 0);

          //  calculates the total digits in card
  long digitcounter = cardnumber;
  while(digitcounter > 0)
  {
    digitcounter = digitcounter / 10;
    digits++;
  }

  if (digits != 13 &&  digits != 15 && digits != 16)
  {   // 2-2
    printf("INVALID");
  }    // 2-2
  else
    { // 2

    //  Breaks down the credit card number into individual integers
  int digit1 = (cardnumber / 1000000000000000);
  int digit2 = (cardnumber / 100000000000000) % 10;
  int digit3 = (cardnumber / 10000000000000) % 10;
  int digit4 = (cardnumber / 1000000000000) % 10;
  int digit5 = (cardnumber / 100000000000) % 10;
  int digit6 = (cardnumber / 10000000000) % 10;
  int digit7 = (cardnumber / 1000000000) % 10;
  int digit8 = (cardnumber / 100000000) % 10;
  int digit9 = (cardnumber / 10000000) % 10;
  int digit10 = (cardnumber / 1000000) % 10;
  int digit11 = (cardnumber / 100000) % 10;
  int digit12 = (cardnumber / 10000) % 10;
  int digit13 = (cardnumber / 1000) % 10;
  int digit14 = (cardnumber / 100) % 10;
  int digit15 = (cardnumber / 10) % 10;
  int digit16 = (cardnumber % 10);

  //  multiplies 2 to every odd number 
  int multi_odd15 = (digit15 * 2);
    while (multi_odd15 > 9)
    {
        int check1 = multi_odd15 % 10;
        int check2 = multi_odd15 / 10;
        multi_odd15 = check1 + check2;
    }
  int multi_odd13 = (digit13 * 2);
    while (multi_odd13 > 9)
    {
        int check1 = multi_odd13 % 10;
        int check2 = multi_odd13 / 10;
        multi_odd13 = check1 + check2;
    }
  int multi_odd11 = (digit11 * 2);
    while (multi_odd11 > 9)
    {
        int check1 = multi_odd11 % 10;
        int check2 = multi_odd11 / 10;
        multi_odd11 = check1 + check2;
    }
   int multi_odd9 = (digit9 * 2);
    while (multi_odd9 > 9)
    {
        int check1 = multi_odd9 % 10;
        int check2 = multi_odd9 / 10;
        multi_odd9 = check1 + check2;
    }
   int multi_odd7 = (digit7 * 2);
    while (multi_odd7 > 9)
    {
        int check1 = multi_odd7 % 10;
        int check2 = multi_odd7 / 10;
        multi_odd7 = check1 + check2;
    }
  int multi_odd5 = (digit5 * 2);
    while (multi_odd5 > 9)
    {
        int check1 = multi_odd5 % 10;
        int check2 = multi_odd5 / 10;
        multi_odd5 = check1 + check2;
    }
  int multi_odd3 = (digit3 * 2);  
    while (multi_odd3 > 9)
    {
        int check1 = multi_odd3 % 10;
        int check2 = multi_odd3 / 10;
        multi_odd3 = check1 + check2;
    }
  int multi_odd1 = (digit1 * 2);
    while (multi_odd1 > 9)
    {
        int check1 = multi_odd1 % 10;
        int check2 = multi_odd1 / 10;
        multi_odd1 = check1 + check2;
    }

    //sum of odd number
   odd = (multi_odd15 + multi_odd13 + multi_odd11 + multi_odd9 + multi_odd7 + multi_odd5 + multi_odd3 
       + multi_odd1);

    //  Sum of all the even numbers
   even = (digit2 + digit4 + digit6 + digit8 + digit10 + digit12 + digit14 + digit16);

    //  Code to check if the card number is possible
   if ((odd + even) % 10 == 0)
   { // 3    
    //  If the card number is 13 digits
    if (digits == 13)
    { // 4
        int checkvisa1 =  cardnumber / 1000000000000;
        if (checkvisa1 == 4)
        {
            printf("Visa\n");
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("INVALID\n");
        }
      } // 4  
    } //3

    //  If the card number is 15 digits
    else if (digits == 15)
    { // 5
        int checkamex = cardnumber / 10000000000000;
        if (checkamex == 34 && checkamex == 37)
        {
            printf("American express\n");
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("INVALID\n");
        }
    } // 5

    //  If the card number is 16 digits
    else
    { // 6
        int checkmaster = cardnumber / 100000000000000;
        int checkvisa2 = cardnumber / 1000000000000000;

        if (checkmaster <= 55 && checkmaster > 50)
        {
           printf("Mastercard\n");
        }
        else if (checkvisa2 == 4)
        {
           printf("Visa\n");
        }
        else
        {
           printf("INVALID\n");
        }
      } // 6

     } // 2

   } // 1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take some time to read [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then tell us what output you expect, and what you get. Does it return but print nothing? Does it not return at all? What is it you are trying to do and where you are stuck.

Comment: To improve the code a lot you should start learning about arrays and loops. Also as you handle each digit separately you should probably not handle the card number as an integer but as a string. Also indentation is important.

Comment: Two tips: 1. A card number is not a numeric value, and therefore not suitable for an `int`. 2. When you have variables named like `foo1`, `foo2`, etc., maybe you should use an array.

Comment: `long` may only hold 32-bits (about 9/10 decimal digits).  Better to use `long long` here.

Comment: "Everything works right except with a Visa 411111111111111"  --> post examples that worked.  Certainly you have not tried all 13+ digits numbers and only failed one.

Comment: This will never be true: `if (checkamex == 34 && checkamex == 37)`. Doesn't support your statement "Everything works right except with a Visa"

Answer (score 1):

This `else if (digits == 15)` is executed *only when* `if ((odd + even) % 10 == 0)` is false. That is probably not the flow control you had in mind. It is more likely that it should be "paired" with this `if (digits == 13)`.

When this `if ((odd + even) % 10 == 0)` is true, the next test is `if (digits == 13)`, which is false in the `4111111111111111` example, so no output is created And it is done with the block.  The `else if` and the next `else` blocks aren't executed (because the luhn's test evaluated to true), so the program just.... ends.